# Can i have a distribution that is not a marginal of another distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions

Can there be a distribution that cannot be expressed as a marginal of some other distribution?

Comment: Try in reverse: given a distribution, is it ever impossible to construct a joint distribution of which the original distribution is marginal?

Comment: Every distribution is a marginal of itself.  Less trivially, and more intuitively, suppose $X$ is a random variable with a given distribution and let $Y$ be independent of $X.$  How is the distribution of $X$ related to that of $(X,Y)$?  All you need to do now is show such a $Y$ exists.  Consider any constant random variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is **NO**.

To reformulate the question: Given any two univariate distributions $F, G$ (represented with their cumulative distribution functions) is there always a bivariate distribution with  $F, G$ as marginals? Yes, for instance by independence.

Comment: And this applies for multivariate distributions, too.